# Am I wrong in table design or wrong in selected index when made the table?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, indexing

I've build web application as a tool to eliminate unnecessary data in peoples table, this application mainly to filter all data of peoples who valid to get an election rights. At first, it wasn't a problem when the main table still had few rows, but it is really bad (6 seconds) when the table is filled with about 200K rows (really worse because the table will be up to 6 million rows).

I have table design like below, and I am doing a join with 4 tables (region table start from province, city, district and town). Each region table is related to each other with their own id:

```
CREATE TABLE `peoples` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_prov` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `id_city` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `id_district` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `id_town` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
    `tps` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
    `urut_xls` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `nik` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `place_of_birth` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `birth_date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `age` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sex` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `marital_s` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
    `note` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `m_name` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `m_birthdate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `format_birthdate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `m_sex` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT ,
    `m_m_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `sex_double` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_import` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
    `id_workspace` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stat_valid` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `add_manual` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `insert_by` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    `update_by` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mark_as_duplicate` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `mark_as_trash` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    `in_date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ind_import` (`id_import`),
    KEY `ind_duplicate` (`mark_as_duplicate`),
    KEY `id_workspace` (`id_workspace`),
    KEY `tambah_manual` (`tambah_manual`),
    KEY `il` (`stat_valid`,`mark_as_trash`,`in_date_time`),
    KEY `region` (`id_prov`,`id_kab`,`id_kec`,`id_kel`,`tps`),
    KEY `name` (`name`),
    KEY `place_of_birth` (`place_of_birth`),
    KEY `ind_birth` (`birthdate`(10)),
    KEY `ind_sex` (`sex`(2))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

town:

```
CREATE TABLE `town` (
    `id` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
    `id_district` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `id_city` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `id_prov` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    `name_town` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `handprint` blob,
    `pps_1` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pps_2` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pps_3` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `tpscount` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pps_4` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pps_5` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_prov`,`id_kab`,`id_kec`,`id`),
    KEY `name_town` (`name_town`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the query like

```
SELECT `E`.`id`, `E`.`id_prov`, `E`.`id_city`, `E`.`id_district`, `E`.`id_town`, 
  `B`.`name_prov`,`C`.`name_city`,`D`.`name_district`, `A`.`name_town`,
  `E`.`tps`, `E`.`urut_xls`, `E`.`nik`,`E`.`name`,`E`.`place_of_birth`,
  `E`.`birth_date`, `E`.age, `E`.`sex`,   `E`.`marital_s`, `E`.`address`,
  `E`.`note` 
FROM peoples E
JOIN test_prov B ON  E.id_prov = B.id
JOIN test_city C ON E.id_city = C.id 
    AND (C.id_prov=B.id)
JOIN test_district D ON E.id_district = D.id 
    AND ((D.id_city = C.id) AND (D.id_prov= B.id))
JOIN test_town A ON E.id_town = A.id 
    AND ((A.id_district = D.id) 
    AND (A.id_city = C.id) 
    AND (A.id_prov = B.id)) 
    AND E.stat_valid=1 
    AND E.mark_as_trash=0
```

mark_as_trash is a mark column which only contain 1 and zero just to know if the data has been mark as a deleted record, and stat_valid is the filtered result value - if value is 1 then the data is valid to get the rights of election.

I've tried to see the explain but no column is used as an index lookup. I believe that's the problem why the application so slow in 200K rows. The query above only shows two conditions, but the application has a feature to filter by name, place of birth, birth date, age with ranges and so on.

How can I make this perform better?

Comment: How long does it take to fetch 200K rows from the peoples table without any joins? Could you please show definitions for test_prov, test_district and test_city? Maybe using SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/. Could you also provide the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15e70/1/0  Explain output within 200k rows id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,B,ALL,PRIMARY,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,100.00,
1,SIMPLE,C,ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,2,test.B.id,1,100.00,
1,SIMPLE,D,ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,"test.B.id,test.C.id",1,100.00,
1,SIMPLE,A,ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,6,"test.B.id,test.C.id,test.D.id",1,100.00,
1,SIMPLE,E,ref,"il,region",region,8,"test.B.id,test.C.id,test.A.id_district,test.A.id",18834,100.00,"Using where"

Answer (score 0):

Can a city be in two provinces? If not then why do you check `C.id_prov=B.id` if `E.id_city = C.id` should give you just one row?

Also it seems that your query is slow because you're selecting 200k rows. Indexes will improve performance but do you really need all the rows at once? You should use pagination (limit, offset).

Comment: i've used pagination system, actually there is a limit on the last query, but if i try to jump into the last page, it would slow the operation. province cannot be in two cause in province there is a city, district and town and each of those have province id to keep the constraint of relationship.